# Laravel não salva sessão em POPUP

Tags: php, laravel

Na minha página tem 3 opções de Login: E-mail, Facebook e Google.

Quando faço login por e-mail - usando o `Auth::attempt()` - tudo vai bem. Nesse caso eu faço login por um fancybox e não por um *popup*.

Nesse fancybox tem dois botões: um de login para o Facebook e outro para o Google.
Quando clico em ambos os botões abre um *popup* para fazer a requisição no Facebook e retornar. Já testei e está retornando corretamente meus dados quando faço login. Tanto no Facebook como no Google.

E logo abaixo quando uso o `Auth::attempt()`, verifico se o `Auth::check()` está *true*, e está!

Mas eu programei esse popup para fechar sozinho depois da requisição, daí fecha. Quando volto pra página pai e atualizo, a sessão se perde.

Não sei o que pode ser. A única coisa que me vem a cabeça é o *popup*.

Lembrando que é o mesmo domínio tanto na página pai como no *popup*.

OBS: não negativem minha pergunta por falta de código. Eu não posso abrir agora o código para fazer isso. Mas na hora do almoço farei um edit.

---

```
if(id == 'facebook')
   varWindow = window.open(urlBase + '/auth/login-facebook', '_blank', 'width=800, height=700');
else if(id == 'google')   
   varWindow = window.open(urlBase + '/auth/login-google', '_blank', 'width=800, height=700');


# Verificar se usuário já possui um login do Facebook
if(!Input::has('error')){
    $userFacebook   = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

    $idUserProvider = $userFacebook->user['id'];
    $password       = Hash::make($idUserProvider);

    /* 
        Verifica se já tem dados de login do usuário pelo Facebook
        Se não existir cadastra na tabela
        UID User Provider - Facebook
    */

    $verifyUser     = User::whereIdUserProvider($idUserProvider)->first();

    if($verifyUser){
        # Entra no Sistema
        Auth::user()->attempt(['email' => $verifyUser->email, 'id_user_provider' => $idUserProvider, 'password' => $idUserProvider, 'status' => 1]);
}
```

Comment: Diego, seu problema é o o mesmo que deste post, bom eu acredito: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848969/session-variables-lost-in-popup-window/14005284. Dê uma olhada na resposta, bem capaz de ser a mesma coisa.

Comment: @BrunoRigolon e você resolveu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer a autenticação é obrigatório o uso do `intended`.

```
if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
   return redirect()->intended('/painel');
}
```